# How to add proguard file manually in Visual Studio

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, proguard

I am using `Xamarin.Forms`. I want to add Proguard file in my Xamarin.Android project.

Which file do I need to *proguard.cfg* or *progards.txt*.

Are we using `-downwarn` with .dlls or class names?

Comment: Hope this will help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44072278/1318946

Comment: @Pratik - That thread seems different. Could you please tell me which file we using to -downwarn libraries/classes  proguard.cfg or progards.txt?

Comment: I think you are looking for [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/release-prep/proguard?tabs=windows#using-proguard)

Comment: @PratikButani - pl see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got answer.

- First we need to add `proguard.cfg` file to our android project.
- Change file build action to `ProguardConfiguaration`
- Open `proguard.cfg` file to Notepad++ and change Ecoding to UTF-8(without BOM)
- If your are getting warnings add `-dontwarn` attribute followed by package name.
  like `-dontwarn com.appdynamics.eumagent.**` without using keyword `class`.
- Clean project after adding `.cfg` file

Now ProGuard should work.